# Pass an attribute to an external javascript file in thymeleaf- passed as empty string

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

From my controller I add an Object to my model, which I can access within the Html.
example

```
 redir.addFlashAttribute("userId",userId);
 return modelAndView;
```

Within the HTML if I access the userId

```
 <input type="hidden" id="userId" th:value="${userId}" /> -
```

I can see the result.
I have an external JS file, that has a function that takes as an input parameter userId.
How do I read the userId directly to the JS file ?
Cuz if I do it like this :

```
var userId=$("userId").val();
```

the userId doesn't take the value. It shows an empty string. 
How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use selector for id in html `#userId`

```
var userId=$("#userId").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `val` method looks at the `value` attribute, so it ignores `th:value`. You need to use the `.attr` method, e.g. `$('#userId).attr('th-value')`.